# Android startActivities Intent Order

Tags: android, android-intent

My app needs to show dialog activity as overlay on App's setting Screen. That's why app need to start multiple activities at once.

For this I have used startActivities method.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", mContext.getPackageName(), null);
    intent.setData(uri);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("SettingsItems", "Items");

    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, AutoStartSettingsActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(bundle);

    Intent[] intents = new Intent[2];
    intents[0] = intent;
    intents[1] = i;

    startActivities(intents);
```

But it always start AutoStartSettingsActivity activity first (which is in my App) and then App Settings screen. That's why Settings screen over dialog activity, which is reverse.

I did try to change intent order but fail:

```
 Intent[] intents = new Intent[2];
 intents[0] = i; 
 intents[1] = intent;
```

so the question what intent order should be applied in startActivities intent array so dialog activity can show over App Settings screen.

Answer (score 0):

In order to launch deep, try to start your activities one by one.

```
Intent a = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(a);

Intent b = new Intent(this, DialogActivity.class);
startActivity(b);
```

Like this you can start your activities a and b at the same time, suppress transition to SettingsActivity, and getting a single transition from your current activity to DialogActivity.

Comment: In this SettingsActivity also overlay DialogActivity  (It is rare i.e. this works 90% times but still an issue.)

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee the order in which the activities are launched, I would do the following:

- Launch `SettingsActivity`
- when `onPause()` is called in your app, launch the dialog `AutoStartSettingsActivity`

If this doesn't work you may need to add some delay before you launch the `AutoStartSettingsActivity`

Comment: Well, in order to ensure that this works you would need to monitor when the Settings activity is displayed and launch your dialog activity after that. It is possible to do this using the accessibility service, but this is complete overkill for your problem, you will need to get special permission from the user and the user probably won't understand why you need it.

Comment: Then this is probably the best that you can do. Make the delay longer if you feel it isn't working